# Align text to bottom with shape-outside applied?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have some text which I wrap using shape-outside. How do I **align it to bottom?**

Using flexbox on the parent destroys the float, hence no more wrapping. Using absolute positioning just ignores the shape.

```css
main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: dotted 1px lightgray;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed mattis odio. Vestibulum viverra est quis fermentum pulvinar. Morbi feugiat pretium massa, id accumsan lacus tempus nec.</span>
</main>
```

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by *align to bottom*. Can you show a sample (maybe an image or something else) of the output that you need?

Comment: @Harry I guess, he wants text to align to the bottom of box. As we add more text, it start moving upwards but keep its alignment with shape outside property... For now, text is aligned with shape-outside but its top aligned in the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `offsetHeight` of the outer element, subtract the height of the text and put the result as top padding. However that leaves a gap because now that the text went further down it has a smaller height and the calculation comes a bit off. So, what I did (there must be a better sollution) was to calculate it three times. Check it out:

```js
var mainHeight = document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight;

var oldHeight = document.getElementById('insider').offsetHeight;
var padding = (mainHeight-oldHeight);
document.getElementById("text").style.padding = padding+"px 0 0 0";

//Two more times to fix the gap

oldHeight = document.getElementById('insider').offsetHeight;
padding = (mainHeight-oldHeight);
document.getElementById("text").style.padding = padding+"px 0 0 0";

oldHeight = document.getElementById('insider').offsetHeight;
padding = (mainHeight-oldHeight);
document.getElementById("text").style.padding = padding+"px 0 0 0";
```

```css
main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: dotted 1px lightgray;
  background-color:wheat;
}

main div.empty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 0 100%); 
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="text" id="text"><span id="insider">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed mattis odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed mattis odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed mattis odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Using Javascript seems overkill. Plus the OP did not ask for Javascript. I too have the same problem and having to use javascript drives me mad because this is a formatting issue. Javascript is for events.

Comment: @Xavier do you have a non-JS solution to offer then? "Javascript is for events" seems like nonsense, if JS is required to accomplish the behavior.